# How to convert from Java to Xamarin C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Can someone help me convert the following from Java to C# (Xamarin)?

I tried a couple of different ways, but I cannot get it to work.

The code is:

```java
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

// Break out all extra HTTP header lines and add it to the HttpPost object
for (String line : contentType.replace("\r", "\n").split("\n")) {
    if (line.length() > 0 && line.contains(":")) {
        String[] parts = line.split(":", 2);
        if (parts.length == 2) {
            post.addHeader(parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());
        }
    }
}

// Create a byte array entity for the POST data, the content
// type here is only used for the postEntity object
ByteArrayEntity postEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(challenge);
postEntity.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
post.setEntity(postEntity);

// Create a HttpClient and execute the HttpPost filled out above
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

// Get the response entity out of the response
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Comment: where do you have problems? StackOverflow is not a code converting service.

Comment: The part that I having the most trouble with is the 
 post.SetEntity(postEntity);.  How do I the equivalent in Xamarin? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are stuck with

```
post.SetEntity(postEntity);
```

then it converts to:

```
ByteArrayEntity postEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(challenge);
postEntity.SetContentType("application/octet-stream");
post.Entity = postEntity;
```

When converting to Java from C# you mostly have to change the property names to start with upperCase and then if you get stuck on certain objects I would look check out the Xamarin API Docs, HttpPost class linked [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Org.Apache.Http.Client.Methods.HttpPost/).